# React Starter Kit: Introduce constant for client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook

Im starting with NodeJS using the React Starter Kit, now I came across following problem:

My Top-Level-Component has an prop *likesCount* which holds the number of likes the associated facebook page currently has. This property should be set once on every page load, by some method calling the FB API using the app access token, which is why I dont want this script executed on the client side.

And it is not really important enough to set up an API service for this number.

So roughly, how can I introduce a constant (the likes count) once a side is loaded and keep it during the following session as an prop (especially on the client side?)

My App.js (root component)

class App {

```
static propTypes = {
    path          : PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    pageLikes     : PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    viewport      : PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    onSetTitle    : PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    onSetMeta     : PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    onPageNotFound: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

server.js

```
server.get( '*', function ( req, res ) {
   var data  = { description: '' };
   var app   = new App( {
      path          : req.path,
      pageLikes     : currentPageLikes(),
      onSetTitle    : function ( title ) {
          data.title = title;
      },
      onSetMeta     : function ( name, content ) {
          data[ name ] = content;
      },
      onPageNotFound: function () {
          res.status( 404 );
      }
   } );

   data.body = React.renderToString( app );
   var html  = template( data );
   res.send( html );
} );
```

app.js

```
function run() {
// Render the top-level React component
    let props   = {
       path          : path,
       onSetTitle    : ( title ) => document.title = title,
       onSetMeta     : setMetaTag,
       onPageNotFound: emptyFunction
    };

    let element = React.createElement( App, props );
    React.render( element, document.body );
    ...
```

clearly I should set the property in app.js too, but I dont know where I can store this number so that I can access it on the client side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay it seems the only way is to use placeholders, e.g.

```
<script>var likesCount =  <%- JSON.stringify(likesCount) %>;<script>
```

and in server.js

```
data.likesCount = likesCount;
```

results in a globally available variable likesCount on the client.